# Array Out of Bounds Exception in 2D array - how can I avoid this?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a begginer in Java and I am writing a program to solve mazes, as an assignment. Right now, I'm having a hard time with something that may be pretty stupid on the part that reads the maze from a cvs file, but I just can't fix it.

I get `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception for the line that says "`while (info[x] != null) {`", for some reason. I need to check if the array element is empty or not for my program to run, but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
public class Project5v2 
{

static String mazecsv = "/Users/amorimph/Documents/COMP 182/Project 5/mazeinput.csv";
static File solvedMaze = new File("/Users/amorimph/Documents/COMP 182/Project 5/solvedMaze.txt");
static int[][] maze = new int[50][50];
static int trigger = 0;
static int mazeWidth;
static int mazeHeight;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    readCSV(mazecsv);
    start(maze);
    mazeToString(maze);

}

public static void readCSV(String csvfile) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ",";
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;


    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        br.readLine();

           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

               String[] info = line.split(csvSplitBy);

               while (info[x] != null) {                       
                   maze[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(info[x]);
                   x++;
                   mazeWidth = x;
               }
               y++;
               x = 1;
               mazeHeight = y;

           }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this to a `for loop`

```
while (info[x] != null) {                       
      maze[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(info[x]);
      x++;
      mazeWidth = x;
}
```

to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < info.length; x++) {                       
      maze[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(info[x]);
}
mazeWidth = info.length;
```

This is assuming that `info` will not be greater than `50`, which is the size that you have defined for `maze`.  If this is not guaranteed then

```
for (int x = 0; x < info.length && x < maze.length; x++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error on that line because there is nothing to stop x from incrementing to a number BEYOND the greatest row value in maze. So one thing that you could do if you wanted to keep the while loop is add another condition.

Just add this to your while loop, IFF you need or want to keep the while around.

```
while(info[x] != null && x < maze.length)
{
     //magicalness
}
```

The additional boolean statement prevents the OutOfBounds error by making sure x is not greater than the number of rows in the 2D array or the length of the array called info.

Comment: @Downvoter please explain your reason for downvoting my answer